# Extract CID & LAC from android device uisng api call(python)

Tags: android, python, google-api, odoo, odoo-10

I am using Google's geolocation api and geocode api to track any android device using nearest tower location.

For using geolocation, CID & LAC needs to be sent as one of the required parameters to get the tower detials the device is connected to. I need this functionality in Odoo framework.

Both the details I could see when I dial '*#*#4636#*#*' from the device.
If I statically pass CID and LAC to google API, everything works fine. 
My question is how to get CID and LAC of a device using an api call ??